# htaccess apply rule to all but two domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

here's the current situation
we have multiple domains on same server (brand protection) pointing at the same content.
All have been redirected to one default domain with 301 redirection.
However, i got a task to exclude one domain from the rule (with or without www).

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.basicdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.basicdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So after the change it should say

If user types basicDomain2.com or www.basicDomain2.com do nothing. 
If user types any other doman name with or without www, make redirection to www.basicdomain.com

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one:

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?basicdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.basicdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The ()? arround www. should make it optional.

Comment: I think that this would solve the problem with basicdomain2.com, since it should not be redirected?